How can we elevate developer performance in a shared codebase?
In our company, we have multiple software development teams working on a common codebase. The problem we are facing is that developers are not producing good results when they work on code that they did not originally write. Skill-wise, we have developers at roughly three levels:

A. Able to deliver work in a timely manner and without defects. Many
developers are at this level when working on their own code, but
almost nobody is at this level when working on someone else's code.
B. Able to deliver work with the help of someone from level A.
However, the work usually takes longer to complete and the result is
not as good as if done by an A-level developer. The majority of our
developers are at this level.
C. Not able to deliver work without extensive help from A and B
developers.

Note that there's no clear correlation between seniority and the above levels. However, there is a correlation between the type of code the developer is working on (own vs. others') and their level.
We don't have any formal rules regarding who should or shouldn't work on any particular code. Officially, everyone should be able to work on anything. However, because the problem is well known in the organization, product managers tend to try to allocate only A-level developers for their needs. This is not optimal resource allocation and might not always be possible. If a new feature or a bug fix requires changes in multiple places in the code, it is much easier to find 1–2 B-level developers than 5–10 A-level developers.
How can we solve this problem? How can we bring B and C-level developers up to A level? Is it even worth trying? Theoretically, we could abandon the common codebase and start building multiple codebases from scratch, one for each team. This would mean that each team would reinvent the wheel, but at least it would be their own wheel. Does that make sense?
P.S. Before you suggest better testing: we do have a lot of tests, but test developers face the exact same problem, and it is even worse for them.

Do you have codereviews / Pull Requests? For us that is a great equalizers.

Yes, we do have code reviews. Unfortunately, even the most thorough review will not spot all the bugs. Another problem with the reviews is that developers will not always bother to find the A-level reviewer, but rather ask their closest colleague to review.

What have you done so far to make sure everyone is on the same page? Does all code follow common rules or guidelines? Does everything use the same language/framework? Does everyone use the same tooling?

@user930473 Code reviews NEVER spot all the bugs.

Sounds like the company should only keep A and B. It’s a skill level being unable to maintain legacy code. It’s also a critical skill every developer should have, since all code eventually becomes legacy code, so it’s important to be able to adapt as a developer. You can keep track of developers code quality through code repositories.

"product managers tend to try to allocate only A-level developers for their needs. This is not optimal resource allocation and might not always be possible"
Maybe product managers should not do the allocation then?

I think this question would be better for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ or https://stackoverflow.com

I'm going to suggest a few measures that you could take (or lobby for - your role in this is not really clear). This is by no means a complete list, and it also does not mean that everything has to be done.
This answer assumes that this is a structural issue. If the problem is with the skills of individual people, solutions would lie more in the direction of providing training, reviewing hiring practices, ...
Make sure that as many things as possible are consistent throughout your codebase
That includes e.g.

languages and frameworks
tools and environments necessary to run/test the code
coding guidelines
how documentation is written and where it is kept
workflows (e.g. pull requests)

Ensure everyone has a high-level understanding of the whole codebase

What is the purpose of the system?
How is the codebase structured?
High-level architecture

You could for example organize introduction sessions with architects.
Reduce the amount of knowledge that is kept only in the head of the initial developers

Ensure a minimum of documentation (architecture, requirements, reasons for important decisions, ...)
Explicitly communicate expectations regarding when a task is done (Is it tested? Documented? Who needs to review? ...)
Review code not just for correctness but also for understandability
Organize hands-on sessions with experts of each part of the system

Allow for learning even if this takes more time

Let your expert developers mark tasks/bugs that are not very time-critical, not too large and don't require a very deep understanding. If possible, someone other than that expert should take over those tasks.
Let developers pair up with someone who usually works on something different (but somewhat related)
Make sure your experts have enough time to review code from less experienced (in that area) developers
Reward knowledge sharing, not just progress on features or bugs solved (e.g. as part of annual reviews)

Get buy-in from as many people as possible

While managers will always want fast progress, most of them can also be convinced that it is a good thing if a project doesn't break down completely because one or two people get sick/quit/...
Ask developers what makes it hard for them to work with code they have not written themselves
Ask others for ideas and involve them in the solution

Keep your expectations realistic
It is always easier to work with code that one knows well. I would find it very surprising if anyone were as fast when working with code they have never seen before as with code they are already familiar with.
It is a good goal to spread out knowledge and for multiple people to be able to work with each part of the codebase. But you need to be aware that this is going to take time - more of it in the beginning, but also later on to keep up with changes as they are made.

Whilst I agree with your analysis that the issue is knowledge-sharing, I think software managers often under-estimate the cost of things like producing and maintaining documentation, or pairing/tripling up the people working on a task (that can be done by one person if the knowledge isn't shared). And they over-estimate the effectiveness of various strategies. The real issue is that the costs of knowledge-sharing are simply too large for most businesses to bear.

@Steve True, but the cost of not sharing at all can also be very high. These are also not things to do indiscriminately, and a lot depends on the environment. It is no use to have 100 people know everything, but for anything important you want at least two who know it well and a few more who could get up to speed in a decent amount of time. It's also a matter of the cost of errors and the required quality. I work on a complex system in a heavily regulated industry and I know that what I do affects human lives, so I'm likely biased in the direction of caution.

@Steve Pairing up can speed up some very specific tasks - where the probability (and cost) of making errors is high enough that it's worth making sure you get it right on the first try, instead of going back to hunt bugs later. Definitely not worth it for every run-of-the-mill task unless you are doing it for training. Personally I don't even like pair programming that much, but occasionally doing so with a colleague who took over some things from me has been quite efficient in enabling him to work on those on his own now.

Review code not just for correctness but also for understandability - actually you can't review for correctness something you fail to understand. So either the PR is reviewed by someone who participated in its development (great idea, but insufficient) or it isn't reviewed at all and just "clicked through". In either case, code review is something to focus on: set up rules that prevent merging without approval, and always make sure that somebody who did not take part in this work says LGTM.

Are they testing the right thing and edge cases? Are they testing expecting failures?
Saying:

P.S. Before you suggest better testing: we do have a lot of tests,
but test developers face the exact same problem, and it is even worse
for them.

This just doesn't match the desired results. Something doesn't match. Where is the disconnect?
Even the most icky spaghetti code is better than buggy code if does what it is supposed to.
You question likely comes down to discipline. They are currently either "throwing the code over the wall" and it is someone's problem. Or "throwing the code at the wall and seeing what sticks". Or maybe the worst case, "kicking the can" down the road and not addressing known tech debt.
Consider - for a few weeks - asking for each bug found, where are the tests that missed it. Require updating the tests before fixing the code.
If the tests fail to catch the bugs then either the bugs are really esoteric and you're very unlucky, or the tests are giving you and your team a false sense of security. Doing the forensics on the tests is the only way to find out which.
If the developer can't write the test, how the heck can they write the method? IMO
This, IMHO, is way to start to fix your problem. Accountability is a wonderful thing.

In the question I mentioned that "the result is not as good as if done by an A-level developer". I don't mean only the bugs, but overall architectural design quality, readability, extensibility etc. things which are not easily testable.
I personally see tests as the last line of defense. Sure, improving tests coverage and tests quality can help, but it will not solve the core issue of lack of understanding of someone else's code. Why e.g. A-level developers can work and produce good results even on the code without high test coverage?

@user930473  In my company, some of our codebase is 40 years old. There is no way anyone that isn't about to retire is comfortable with all of it. Not all developers we will hire or have budget to hire will be "A" level. Writing the test first is the backstop. I didn't used to believe it. Now I demand it of my teams. Almost every bug that hits QA at my company is tied to a skimped or skipped test. Everything else programming is fluid - how to manage, frameworks, document, etc. The concept of testing is pretty stable. NOW - to your point. Document the design pattern for new / touched code.

100% what DogBoy37 says. Tests are not "the last line of defence", they are documentation of what the code currently does, they ensure your codebase is modular and has a good design, they tell you when you're breaking the existing code

You have to be pragmatic and work with what you've got. Deadlines must be met. Requiring good work and having a known codebase go hand-in-hand. Readable code is a must. How do you measure readability? Code review is supposed to be part of that process. Having a written design pattern is supposed to help. Being real - it is very painful cleaning up someone else's code if it isn't clear what they were trying to do or thinking. But it is no excuse to continue that behavior. There is no magic wand. No overnight cures. That is why I suggest taking every new bug back to the test that didn't find it.

For each portion of the codebase, identify who is an A-level developer.  Those people (or that person) will be the only ones allowed to do code reviews on that code.  If you have no A-level developer for a portion of the codebase (e.g. the original developer left), you will have to pick a B-level developer to take on that role.  Note that such developers need to be more skilled than average, as they won't have an A-level developer to help them.
The person who is supposed to do the code review should be identified before the task is started, so that coders can't avoid a rigorous code review by sending it to their cronies.
When assigning tasks, always assign B-level coders with A-level reviewers.  This will help you elevate B-level to A-level on that portion of the codebase while keeping the existing A-level in touch with the code.  Yes, this is less "efficient" than just having the A-level developer work on it, but it also means that you have a backup in case the A-level developer leaves.
For C-level developers, see if they can operate at B-level with an A-level reviewer.  If so, give them new code to write.  If they become A-level on that code, great.  If they can't operate at A-level on code they wrote and B-level on other code, let them go.
If you have an important portion of the codebase with no A-level developers, consider rewriting it.  Sometimes code is so messy that it is impossible to learn at less effort than rewriting.  Sure, try assigning a developer to learn it first, but be prepared for the developers to fail.
Managing this kind of complexity is also why they have service-oriented architectures (SOA).  In SOA, the system is broken into smaller systems or services.  You don't need everyone to be experts on the entire system.  You develop expertise at the service level.  Other developers only interact with the service at the interface level.  As a result, they don't need to know the details of the transformation from input to output, only the outcome.  Try to have two developers at A-level on each service with B-level developers to share the workload.
Not every company is large enough to need SOA.  If you have less than eight developers, then probably not.  That's small enough that all the developers can be on the same team.  If you have more than one team, then consider ways (e.g. SOA) to split the work between teams such that the teams can focus.  Note that you may go directly from one team to three or more teams.  Because once you split, it takes a lot more resources to manage the complexity.
Two (or more) teams should not share a codebase.  Find ways to split the codebase such that only one team needs to be responsible.  Yes, this will add more communication overhead, but it is necessary if you need multiple teams.

"You don't need everyone to be experts on the entire system. You develop expertise at the service level. Other developers only interact with the service at the interface level. As a result, they don't need to know the details of the transformation from input to output, only the outcome." - you do still need people who understand the system as a whole though, and who are capable of designing the interfaces sensibly, and supervising the interactions of all the different parts that ensue. You also need careful controls on the complexity and schedule of interactions across interfaces.


there is a correlation between the type of code the developer is working on (own vs. others') and their level.

That's because the vast majority of developer time and effort is spent on learning an understanding of the situation, including the purpose to be served by the computer application, and how the code corresponds to the purpose.
The only time that someone other than the writer of the code will have the same understanding as the original writer, is when the code is exceptionally well-structured, when the original writer had an exceptionally simple and sound understanding, when the original writer has spent time to convey their understanding to the non-writer, and when the non-writer has skill and experience in learning by listening/reading rather than doing development.
In reality, this reproductive process is expensive and usually falls down - it's usually more feasible and economical to just have new developers start the code from scratch each time.
Most businesses, the second they lose all the original developers of a codebase, further productivity on that codebase drops to something like 1% - or some tiny fraction - of what it was with the creators present.
So I wouldn't be surprised to find what you're experiencing. It's broadly normal.
And unless you have completely abnormal amounts of resources to spend - like investment banks, who can hire the best graduates, who have academics on staff, who have people whose role in development is purely to spend all day talking and writing to others about it, and so on - then there's really nothing you can hope to do about it.
Without all that extraordinary infrastructure for sharing and reproducing knowledge, the only time a team of developers are really interchangeable for performing new development on a codebase they haven't written, is when they are mostly writing masses of boilerplate dealing with essentially simple problems. In other words, when complexity is limited to the point that you just don't need much knowledge to be able to understand what's going on and how to do it.

I wonder if there's a threshold beyond which it could be concluded that the costs of knowledge-sharing are too high and are not worth paying? Are there any studies on this topic?

@user930473, I'm not aware of any studies. A problem is that in a competitive market, it's a competitive advantage not to share and reproduce knowledge. Even if it leads to a collapse of business capability eventually, it might be long after the reproducers have been put out of business and the non-reproducers have solidified their market share, so once the capability of the non-reproducers collapses through lack of reproduction, they still have no competition from anything better and can still survive at the new lower standard. (1/3)

Another aspect of the problem is that things do change over time - business operations grow, shrink, or otherwise alter in a way that requires significant rework of their information systems, and technologies change too. Reproducing knowledge necessary to explain and adapt old systems can require a lot of historical knowledge that is no longer essential. It's often easier to redevelop, or even set up a new business afresh, than reproduce knowledge about how the cruft used to correspond to something important. (2/3)

Finally, many businesses are only concerned about knowledge reproduction so that they can continue to treat developers as cheap replaceable cogs rather than essential managers. Some of the worst businesses can have 100% turnover every couple of years or less. For these, the most financially effective solution to retaining business knowledge, would be to just retain the developers themselves. It's only massive corporations who exist and maintain systems for longer than the whole professional careers of a single generation of staff, for whom that approach cannot work. (3/3)

You have a few possible solutions open to you.
One is to divide the code so different teams own different bits. Code ownership isn't ideal, but neither is the situation you are in. The issue here is adding bureaucracy. To make this work, if team A needs a change to code owned by team B, they have to request it from them, as well as specifying exactly what they need done. This is going to slow down development. On the other hand it will result in fewer bugs. It's a trade-off. Decide where the right point of the trade-off is for you. In software development everything is a trade-off.
Slightly less restrictively you can assign each part of your code to a couple of your A-level developers who know the code well. Each piece of code has at least 2 A-levels assigned to it. Anyone else working on that code must seek the guidance of one of the relevant A-levels before starting, and all code changes on that code must be reviewed by one of them. This will slow down the development process less than the above, but it might mean your A-level developers do more reviewing and less developing. This may not make them happy, but it's the eventual fate of anybody who is good at programming and wants to be a team player.
You can also spend a significant amount of time getting your B and C developers up to the point where they don't create as many bugs. This again is going to require lots of effort from your A developers. They need to do training and walkthroughs of key pieces of code, to make sure everybody understands them. Again this requires substantial non-coding effort from your A players, but hopefully only for a short period of time.
If your tests aren't up to scratch then get them up to scratch. You might also look at the modularity of your code. Most code routines and classes should have clearly defined and understood functionality, and inadvertant mistakes while modifying them is often a sign that they don't. Maybe some substantial refactoring is in order.
From your comments it looks like the current situation is due to a previous reorganisation. In that case this should be addressed at the same level as the reorganisation was planned and executed, presumably by management more senior than you. Somebody should analyse the current productivity (bug rate is a part of productivity) to see if the reorg achieved its goals or if some other changes are required.

Previously our organization was like what you describe in your first paragraph. We then were reorganized to what I described in my question. This was done in order to decrease bureaucracy and increase development pace. It is not clear were those goals achieved or not.

@user930473 There should be somebody who is in a position to do an analysis to find out if those goals were achieved. In fact it really should have been done something like a year after the reorganization.

At the core of your question is this:

developers are not producing good results when they work on code that they did not originally write

If you want to ever have a significantly sized codebase, (> 20M lines of code), everything will tend towards that case
So your devs will need to learn to do that well
In order to be able to patch existing code, it has to be written well
Most definitely you should not resort to "reinventing the wheel", that's a really bad practice and you should do what you can to avoid it

First off, this is a product management issue, not an individual developer issue. If you are not the product manager, then you don't have a say in what is happening.
If the company does not have a manager whose job includes managing the common code base (VP of Programming?), that is a top management issue. Again, not an individual developer issue.
Thus, the solution has to be proposed at the corporate level. That means showing that the current way of operating is costing the company money. Then, show that by changing things, the company will save money, reduce time to market of new products, and provide higher quality products to the market. The cost of changing has to be less than the current costs or has to be more in line with the corporate strategy. These types of changes often are best proposed by the sales department. (So, finding a salesperson who understands what you are trying to propose and getting that person to bring it to top management is often a smart tactic.)
